# Understanding this recursive combination generator

Tags: javascript, recursion, ecmascript-6, generator, combinatorics

I found this code for generating a generator function for n choose k combination but I don't quite understand it. Could someone help me explain the steps behind it in plain English? Thanks.

```
const combinations = function*(elements, length) {
  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (length === 1) {
      yield [elements[i]];
    } else {
      let remaining = combinations(elements.slice(i + 1, elements.length), length - 1);
      for (let next of remaining) {
        yield [elements[i], ...next];
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Where did you find it? Please link the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical way to understand a recursive situation like this is to assume it works for the smaller cases and then see how a larger case proceeds.

So let's assume that `combinations(['b', 'c', 'd'], 1)` yields the values `['b']`, then `['c']`, then `'[d]'`, and that similarly `combinations(['c', 'd'], 1)` yields `['c']` then `['d']`, and that `combinations(['d'], 1)` yields just `['d']`, and finally that `combinations([], 1)` yields nothing at all.

Now let's walk through it for `combinations(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2)`:

We iterate over `i` from `0` to `3`:

- when `i` = `0`, `elements[i]` = `'a'` and we see that `length` is `2`, so not `== 1`.  And we calculate `remaining  = combinations(['b', 'c', 'd'], 1)`, which by our assumption yields `['b']` then `['c']` then `['d']`.  So for each one of these we yield `[elements[i], ...(the yielded value)]`, meaning we yield `['a', 'b']`, then `['a', 'c']` then `['a', 'd']`
- when `i` = `1`, `elements[i]` = `'b'` and we see that `length` is `2`, so not `== 1`.  And we calculate `remaining = combinations(['c', 'd'], 1)`, which by our assumption yields `['c']` then `['d']`.  So for each one of these, we yield `[elements[i], ...(the yielded value)]`, meaning we yield `['b', 'c']`, then `['b', 'd']`.
- when `i` = `2`, `elements[i]` = `'c'` and we see that `length` is `2`, so not `== 1`.  And we calculate `remaining = combinations(['d'], 1)`, which by our assumption yields `['d']`.  So for the (only) one of these, we yield, `[elements[i], ...(the yielded value)]`, meaning we yield `['c', 'd']`.
- and when `i` = `3`, `elements[i]` = `'d'` and we see that `length` is `2`, so not `== 1`.  And we calculate `remaining = combinations([], 1), which by our assumption doesn't yield anything, so we also will yield nothing in this case.

Thus, overall, we yielded the following values: `['a', 'b']`, `['a', 'c']`, `['a', 'd']`, `['b', 'c']`, `['b', 'd']`, and `['c', 'd']`, which is exactly the set of combinations of two elements from `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`.

You will of course need to check the base case as well, when `length` = `1`, but that should be easy to do.

### Non-generator approach

There are times when a generator approach makes the code much cleaner and easy to understand.  This, though, is not really one of those times.

Basically, generators allow you to not do complicated gathering of results, but instead to `yield` them as you go.  If you can just as easily gather the results, non-generator code is usually simpler.  Here is the same algorithm not using generators:

```js
const combinations = (elements, length) => 
  elements .flatMap ((el, i) => 
    length == 1
      ? [el]
      : combinations (elements .slice (i + 1), length - 1) 
          .map (combo => [el, ...combo])
  )
  
console .log (combinations (['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

I certainly find that easier to understand.